# Passing additional information in a POST in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I'm in a `new` action and want to pass some extra information to the `create` action (for instance, how many times a user has pressed a given button, `:clicks`).

How should I go about accomplishing the task?

Comment: how about creating a hidden_field and incrementing its value using Jquery every time user press that button !!

Comment: Yup, here's the documentation for the `hidden_field_tag`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag

Comment: that was my first though. my question is more whether if that's the standard way to do things in rails or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'click_count', 0 %>
<%= submit_tag "Click me!", :type => 'button', :onclick => '$("#click_count").val(parseInt($("#click_count").val())+1)' %>
```